# How to print the odd numbers in 2 2D arrays java from user input?

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, printing

I am able to print the 2 2D arrays with the numbers from user input and I am also able to print the odd numbers, but I am having trouble combining the two forms of code so that the odd numbers stay consistent with their cell and not just in one print line. How would I print the odd numbers leaving the non odds as blanks in 2 3x3 arrays?
Heres the code for printing the array:

```
public static void display ( int[][] FirstArray, int[][] SecondArray)
      {
         //Print first array
         System.out.print("Array1: \n");
         for (int row = 0; row < FirstArray.length; row++)
         {
             for(int column = 0; column < FirstArray[row].length; column++)
             {
                 System.out.print(FirstArray[row][column] + " ");
             }
             System.out.println();
         }
         //Print second array
         System.out.print("Array2: \n");

         for (int row = 0; row < SecondArray.length; row++)
         {
             for(int column = 0; column < SecondArray[row].length; column++)
             {
                 System.out.print(SecondArray[row][column] + " ");
             }
             System.out.println();
         } 
      }
ex output:
array 1:     array2
3 3 3        4 4 4
3 3 3        4 4 4
3 3 3        4 4 4
```

Here is the code for printing the odd numbers without in the 3x3 format like the code above:

```
    public static void display(int[][] FirstArray, int[][] SecondArray)
{
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FirstArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FirstArray.length; j++)
        {
            if(FirstArray[i][j]%2==1)
            {
                System.out.println(m1[i][j]);
            }
        }
        }


    for (int i = 0; i < SecondArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SecondArray.length; j++)
        {
            if(SecondArray[i][j]%2==1)
            {
                System.out.println(SecondArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
        }
```

ex output:
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 (odd numbers displayed but in one line)

```
Ex output of what Im looking for(assuming i entered in even numbers too):
3   3    3   
  3      3   3
3          3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redress your print statements in both the loops as :

```
for (int i = 0; i < FirstArray.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < FirstArray.length; j++) {
    if(FirstArray[i][j]%2==1) {
        System.out.print(m1[i][j] + " "); // odd number and space
    } else {
        System.out.print(" "); // blank space for even numbers
    }
  }
  System.out.println(); // next line for next row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter numbers of rows : ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of colmns : ");
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] array = new int[n][m];
        System.out.println("Enter elements of array : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                System.out.print(" X[ " + i + "," + j + "] = ");
                array[i][j] = sc.nextInt();

            }

        }
        System.out.print("Even numbers on position :");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] % 2 != 0) {
                    System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
```